# Anything better than VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have had the opportunity to code using VBA. Most of the VBA Script i have done have been with having Excel in foreground, and excel files not being accessible while the code ran.

Now I am curious to know if there is any ways to keep excel in background and do the cell updation in the same way as it is done on foreground.

---

Update 1:-
By background i mean that the file is not kept open on the desktop, but is being access by the program.

Comment: If your UI is entirely done with UserForms, you can set `Application.Visible = False` in `Workbook_Open()` then show your form.

Comment: Please let me know why you gave -ve vote.

Comment: It's not me who downvoted, but your question is not very clear, you can improve it by following the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you mean by background and foreground, but if your macro is taking too long to run (like minuits) try adding the things below from the article here:

https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Essentially add this at the start of your code:

```
With Application.Excel
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
```

and this at the end:

```
With Application.Excel
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

You can also use

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False 'at the beginning and True at the end
Personally though I have found that the biggest performance upgrade generally comes with deactivating the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `application.ScreenUpdating=False`? This hides all the macro operations while it's running. Or are you trying to make Excel still run while a macro is running? In which case, just open two instances of Excel first, then run macro on one, and work on the other one (but both can't work on the same file).